# following tutorial on vue2 website can't get third party jquery plugin select2 to work

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, jquery-select2

I tried to implement this:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html

I am not making SPA, although I am using Vue components in my page.

> [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function"

found in

I get this error

```
Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function"

found in <Select2> at 
C:\laragon\www\lara\resources\assets\js\components\ui\Select2.vue
```

I include both select2 and my vuejs in the html file:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/content_type_blocks.js') }}?{{ str_random(7) }}"></script>
```

I wonder why do I get the error that select2 is not a function?

Comment: Did you include jQuery as well?

Comment: Sounds like jQuery is not loaded. What happens when you type `$` or `jQuery` in the console?

Comment: yes I do include it as well. I am using another jquery plugin colorpicker, but I was able to get that one working only after putting this in package.json file: "bootstrap-colorpicker": "^2.5.0", and then importing it as a component inside my App.vue using import BootstrapColorPicker from 'bootstrap-colorpicker' and then I was able to use that plugin. but i can't find how to install in package.json select2 as I did with colorpicker, since select2 does not seem to be node package

Comment: after I type $ console prints this: function (a,b){return new r.fn.init(a,b)}

Comment: That shouldn't matter—you can always manually import/include plugins without the need of a package manager, and inject the JS manually using `<script>` tags. Are you sure that the select2 plugin is loaded first?

Comment: I  just typed $('some_value').select2() and it worked, I got this back: r.fn.init {}

Comment: I meant I typed that in the console and got some output so atleast I know select2 is loaded and listening and yes select2 is loaded first as my code above shows

Comment: Is your selector finding what you're trying to select? Are you waiting for the DOM to be ready?

Comment: I am using vue, I am sure vue waits for DOM to be ready before it attempts to attach things to it

Comment: Can you include the code from the *mounted* hook, since that appears to be where the error is happening? Better yet, (bearing in mind you aren't creating a SPA) create an [mcve] using a site like jsbin, jsfiddle, plunker, codepen, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the time when Select2 plugin initializing, jquery had not loaded in a global stack yet.

---

Propose several solutions:

- just add Select2 via NPM `npm install --save select2` and then import it
- I would advise to use more friendly `Selectize.js` Moreover, there is a ready-to-use Vue-component `vue2-selectize`. Also pls look at this performance test: https://jsperf.com/chosen-select2-selectize
- you can try to use a similar solution, written specifically for the Vue: https://github.com/monterail/vue-multiselect